# Dropping MKMapView into Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, mkmapview

I'm using XCode 4 and I just created a subclass of UIViewController, status bar enabled (grey), and dropped in a MKMapView.  My UIView has x,y and w,h of

(0,20) / (320,460)

Then I click on my MKMapView and it has coordinates of:

(0,0) / (320, 460)

Is there a reason that IB doesn't resize itself so the MKMapView will take up the entire screen by making it (0,0)/(320, 480), or putting itself at (0,20)/(320,460)?

The picture below should identify my problem.  Sorry if I am missing something super obvious.  Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add any subview inside a view(container), then that container is the world for that subview, and it'll have co-ordinate according to that. That's why your map view have coordinate(0,0).

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that.  But I guess the problem I am having is I drop my MapView in my UIView what looks like to take up the whole screen, with the coordinate above and it looks fine.  However when I run it in the simulator, there is 20px showing of white space on the bottom that I'm not sure why...